# is there some method to make one function in c++'s class to run in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

if I have one class, is there some method to generate a second thread and call another function? the below is my testing, but cannot work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A
{
public:
    void print_A();
    void print_B();
};

void A::print_A()
{
     std::cout << "in print_A and now need to create another thread and in this thread call print_B" << std::endl;
     std::thread t1(&A::print_B);
     t1.join;
}

void A::print_B()
{
     std::cout << "print_B" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.print_A();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [There probably is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). What have you tried?

Comment: but this can not work.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit your question and include it there instead. And those thread-creations will not work very well as the thread-functions are not `static` member function, which means you need an instance of the class to call the functions on.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to wait for the thread to finish before `print_A` exits, or the program will be terminated. (See e.g. [this `thread` destructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).)

Comment: yes, I will add join()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `std::async`:

```
#include <future>
void A::first_fun()
{
   auto future = std::async(&A::second_fun, this);
   return future.get();
}
```

Note that `future.get()` will block waiting for the thread to complete.

if instead you want to wait for its completion later in the code then you can return the future object and call the `.get()` method later.

Answer (score 1):

Well..you can do something like this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A 
{ 
   public:
    void print_A(); 
    void print_B(); 
};

void A::print_A()
{ 
  std::cout << "in print_A and now need to create another thread and in this       thread call print_B" << std::endl;

  //the changes needed
  std::thread t1(&A::print_B, this);
  t1.join();
 }

void A::print_B() { std::cout << "print_B" << std::endl; } 

int main() { A a; a.print_A(); return 0; }
```

Note: Corrected a typo

Comment: @JamesRoot Thanks for that. I corrected the code now.